# Installed Compass and Sass and compass watch gives error

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I have installed rvm 1.9.2-320, here is my gem list

```
addressable (2.3.5)
breakpoint (2.0.5)
bundler (1.5.3, 1.5.0)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
chunky_png (1.3.0, 1.2.8)
color-schemer (0.2.5)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-aurora (3.0.6)
compass-blend-modes (0.0.2)
compass-normalize (1.4.3)
css_parser (1.3.4)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.1)
minitest (1.6.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.14)
sassy-buttons (0.1.4)
sassy-strings (0.3.1)
singularitygs (1.0.8)
toolkit (1.0.0)
```

When I run compass watch I get this...

```
/Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find chunky_png-1.2.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `setup'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/twhelan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to uninstall sass and reinstall. I have many things but I am missing something and need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved my problem was basically uninstalling the bundle, sass, and compass gem. Then finally figuring out the correct combination of versions that would work with the Drupal Theme that I downloaded.

Two places that helps figure it out in time.

RVM - http://rvm.io/ 
Decent Tut - http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-ruby-sass-and-compass/